# identify special characters in XML python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I have an XML document (example below), I have to read the content along with the special character at the end of the line... In the highlighted portion, I have to extract 'Übernahme-'.

[image]

I have written the below code and able to extract the text:

```
def scandown( elements, indent ):
    s=[]

    for el in elements:
        s.append(el.nodeValue)
        scandown(el.childNodes, indent + 1)
    print(s)

scandown( xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('TC'), 0 )
```

Is there a way to read the characters (TCL CHAR = '-')??

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or markup. Please copy and paste as text.

Comment: Is it the value of the `CHAR` attribute that is the "special character"?

Comment: When I paste the XML text, it turned into a plain text... So I posted a screenshot. Yes, the value of "CHAR" is something I am trying to extract.